# Change the language of iOS virtual keyboard "previous", "next", "done" buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, jquery-mobile, virtual-keyboard

Is there any way with jQuery-Mobile to change the language of the buttons displayed in the top bar of an iPhone/iPad virtual keyboard or to change the texts or remove them at all?

I have seen the language of the "space" and "Go" buttons inside the keyboard depend on the phone language and that is correct, but the buttons in the top bar of the keyboard are always displayed in English to me and I can not find the way to change them...

I am refering to these buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the answer is that if you are using Safari the answer is that it will use the system language, but if you wrap your application with i.e. PhoneGap you can set the 'CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations' to 'Yes' in your info.plist file in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

No you can not change the the language of those buttons.

They are set the system language, so if I set my device to Dutch, those button will be displayed in Dutch.

[image: Keyboard displaying in Dutch]

Comment: You mean setting the language within the "Settings" options? That is the case where "space" and "Go" buttons change their language, but unfortunatelly it does not happen the same for "Previous", "Next" and "Done"...

Comment: Do you know if that bar with the 3 buttons can be removed?

Comment: No you can remove that bar. Weird it works correctly on my devices.

Comment: I'm testing now in an iPad with iOS version 4.3.5 and those buttons remain in English when I change my settings to another language... In 4.3 iPhone and iPad simulators happens the same. I really don't need those buttons, it's a shame that they can not be changed neither removed :-(

Comment: I've just tested it on a device with iOS 4.3.1 and it's still Dutch. Maybe the language your choice is't translate fully by Apple. I suggest you submit a bug report. Also the simulator does not contain a full iOS implementation, so I'm not surprised that it does not work there,

Comment: Thanks for your answers/comments. I am creating an app using PhoneGap and found that these buttons didn't follow the language of the phone. I found that if you go to the InfoPlist.string file in XCode and add the languages you want to support to the Localisation list the buttons will be translated correctly. Hope this helps someone in the future!